# Got warning message when running brew list

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I run `brew list` on my Mac OS X EI Capitan, it will always give me errors message like this --

```
$ brew list
/bin/sh: __rvm_ruby_string_find: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: __rvm_ruby_string_find: line 8: ` ruby-+([1-9]) | ruby-+([1-9]).+([0-9]) | ruby-1.+([1-9]).+([0-9]) | jruby-[19]*)'
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `__rvm_ruby_string_find'
/bin/sh: __rvm_project_ruby_env_load_parse_file: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: __rvm_project_ruby_env_load_parse_file: line 9: ` __rvm_read_lines __variables <( { cat "$1"; echo ""; } | __rvm_sed "${__sed_commands[@]}" )'
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `__rvm_project_ruby_env_load_parse_file'
/bin/sh: __rvm_remove_without_gems: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: __rvm_remove_without_gems: line 2: ` __rvm_read_lines __gems_to_remove <('
/bin/sh: error importing function definition for `__rvm_remove_without_gems'
gdbm        openssl     python      readline    sqlite
```

Image [Link](http://postimg.org/image/m4rwn8j1f/)

Every time running rvm, it will also give me similar error message.

```
$ rvm
bash: __rvm_ruby_string_find: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: __rvm_ruby_string_find: line 8: ` ruby-+([1-9]) | ruby-+([1-9]).+([0-9]) | ruby-1.+([1-9]).+([0-9]) | jruby-[19]*)'
bash: error importing function definition for `__rvm_ruby_string_find'
```

**How can I resolve it? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

OS X ships with an older version of ruby. Use homebrew to install a newer version of ruby and see if that fixes the issue

```
$ brew install ruby
```

You'll also want to make sure that `/usr/local/bin/ruby` is in your `$PATH` before any other ruby version. Honestly, I can't remember if the install does this automatically but it's good to check.

Comment: I just ran the command above, but it still gave me same error. So when you say checking the path, how can I make sure  `/usr/local/bin/ruby`  is in my path. Where can I check it? .profile?

Comment: I print out the $PATH, I can;t find /usr/local/bin/ruby, so does it mean that I need to add it by myself?

Comment: Check the path with `echo $PATH`. 
Then run `brew install ruby`. Read the console output. Most packages will make you aware of any special changes you need to make. If the ruby package does not mention it, then you can add something like `PATH='/usr/local/bin/ruby:${PATH}'` to your bash profile

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem and it still give me same error. After I add the path to $PATH and reinstall ruby by command -- brew install ruby.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling homebrew?

Comment: I tried it, but it looks like it has nothing to do with homebrew. When I install homebrew, it will also give me the error message. http://postimg.org/image/gadkva8rv/

Comment: It's ruby's issue...Very possible. Still can't figure it out :(